# Lazy loading not working on child routes in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

So recently I implemented lazy loading to all my routers. Everything seems to work well, except I just noticed recently that I am unable to navigate to a child's router path. I tried removing the lazy loading and everything works as it supposed to. Any ideas on how I can fix this?

User's flow: The user clicked the `sign up` button and it will navigate the user to the `verify phone` page. After the user is redirected to the `verify phone` page, the user clicked `verify email` to gets redirected to `verify email page`. However instead of being redirected to `verify email page` it just redirects back to `verify phone page`.

This is the router code:

```
{
    path: "/sign-up",
    name: "SignUp",
    component: () => import("@/views/Dashboard/SignUp.vue"),
    children: [
      {
        path: "/sign-up-verify-phone",
        name: "VerifyPhone",
        component: () => import("@/views/Dashboard/VerifyPhone.vue"),
      },
      {
        path: "/sign-up-verify-email",
        name: "VerifyEmail",
        component: () => import("@/views/Dashboard/VerifyEmail.vue"),
      },
      
    ],
  },
```

Comment: Can you link to a reproduction?

Answer (score 1):

some time ago, they changed the `vue-template-compiler`, so you have to return `.default` of the `es6`-module: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1379#issuecomment-298298329

```js
component: () => import("@/views/Dashboard/VerifyEmail.vue").then(c => c.default)
```

Comment: this doesn't work out, I still have the same error.

Comment: which transpiler do you use?